# C_F_POINTER results in undefined array

Tags: c, interop, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

[I have tried to modify code from this this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397188/calling-fortran-from-c-with-deferred-shape-array) to ISO_C_BINDING, but C_F_POINTER call results in Undefined pointer/array (VS2010 debugger) and `print*, f_arr(i)` triggers segmentation fault. I think I do follow closely instructions from [the array interop](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_interopc.htm).

## main.c

```
extern void subr(int, float*);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int N = 3;
    int i;
    float data[3];
    for (i=0;i<N;i++) data[i]=i;
    subr(N,data);
}
```

## sub.f90

```
subroutine subr(n, c_arr) BIND(C)
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING 
implicit none

INTEGER(C_INT),VALUE :: n
TYPE (C_PTR) :: c_arr
REAL(C_FLOAT), POINTER :: f_arr (:)
integer :: i,ml,mu

CALL C_F_POINTER (c_arr, f_arr, (/n/) )
ml = lbound(f_arr,1)
mu = ubound(f_arr,1)

do i=ml,mu
  print*, f_arr(i)
enddo
end subroutine
```

Do you know why I get failure in pointer conversion? (intel fortran compiler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example for calling Fortran from C via the `ISO_C_BINDING` in the Intel documentation is not very clear. But [elsewhere](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.fortran/segmentation-fault-using-f03-c-interoperabi/267610), I have found this explanation: `TYPE (C_PTR) :: X` is equivalent to C's `void **`, i.e. pointer to void pointer. We need `void *`, a void pointer, and therefore must declare `C_ARR` with the `VALUE` attribute:

```
SUBROUTINE SUBR(N, C_ARR) BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING 
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER (C_INT), VALUE :: N
    TYPE (C_PTR), VALUE :: C_ARR
    REAL (C_FLOAT), POINTER :: F_ARR(:)

    CALL C_F_POINTER(C_ARR, F_ARR, (/N/))                                     

    PRINT *, F_ARR

END SUBROUTINE
```

But I'm not sure that you need to call `C_F_POINTER` at all. The following works, too:

```
SUBROUTINE SUBR(N, ARR) BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING 
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER (C_INT), VALUE :: N
    REAL (C_FLOAT) :: ARR(N)

    PRINT *, ARR

END SUBROUTINE
```

(Maybe it is *good practice* to use `C_F_POINTER`, I don't know. That's something the Intel documentation should show: When it is needed and when not.)

**Edit**: After looking a bit more into the interface in the Intel example, I think the `C_F_POINTER` call is needed there, because the array is part of a C `struct`. When declaring your `TYPE`, you cannot make the members arrays of a variable length, so you have to declare the data member as `TYPE (C_PTR)` and go through the `C_F_POINTER` routine.

So here is the same example for passing a pointer to a structure cleaned up:

```
SUBROUTINE SUBR_STRUCT(OBJ) BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING 
    IMPLICIT NONE

    TYPE, BIND(C) :: VECTOR 
        INTEGER (C_INT) :: LEN
        TYPE (C_PTR) :: DATA
    END TYPE VECTOR

    TYPE (VECTOR), INTENT(IN) :: OBJ
    REAL (C_FLOAT), POINTER :: ARR(:)

    CALL C_F_POINTER (OBJ%DATA, ARR, (/OBJ%LEN/))

    PRINT *, ARR

END SUBROUTINE
```

This is called from C thus:

```
struct obj
{
    int len;
    float *data;
};

extern void subr_struct(const struct obj *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float data[] = {0.12, 0.15, 0.18, 0.23, 0.29};
    struct obj o = {5, data};

    subr_struct(&o);

    return 0;
}
```

You can also pass the structure by value if you give `OBJ` the `VALUE` attribute.

Comment: You are right, there is no need to play with the pointer value at all and the shorter version is better (and valid). `type(c_ptr)` without `value` is actually `void **`

Comment: True, but I tried to use [Arr(:) notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397188/calling-fortran-from-c-with-deferred-shape-array?lq=1)

Comment: @VladimirF: Yes, of course, `void **`. Silly typo, the compiler would have caught it. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter You cannot use (:) deferred or assumed shape for `bind(C)` procedure arguments. It is against the standard.