# Passing the allocatable array to subroutine in Fortran with MPI

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I am trying to pass the allocatable array to the subroutine. When I am using the serial version as mentioned in [How to pass allocatable arrays to subroutines in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058743/how-to-pass-allocatable-arrays-to-subroutines-in-fortran) it is working fine. Below is my serial version of code.

```
module test
contains
subroutine func(a,sqa,n)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, intent(in), dimension(:,:) :: a
    integer, intent(out), dimension(:,:):: sqa
    !local variables
    integer :: i,j
    do i= 1,n
        do j = 1,2
            sqa(i,j) = a(i,j)*a(i,j)
            print *, 'i',i, 'j', j,'sqa(i,j)',sqa(i,j)
        end do
    end do
end subroutine func
end module test

program main
use test
implicit none
integer :: n,i,j
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: a, sqa
print *, 'enter no of rows'
read *, n

allocate(a(1:n,2))
allocate(sqa(1:n,2))
do i = 1,n
    do j = 1, 2
        a(i,j) = i +j
        print *, 'i =',i,'j =',j, a(i,j)
    end do
end do
call func(a,  sqa,n)
deallocate(a,sqa)
end program main
```

When I start to implement using MPI, my parallel version of code is

```
module test
 contains
 subroutine func(a,sqa,istart,iend)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: istart, iend
    integer, intent(in), dimension(:,:) :: a
    integer, intent(out),dimension(:,:) :: sqa
    !local variables
    integer :: i,j
    do i= istart, iend
        do j = 1,2
            sqa(i,j) = a(i,j)*a(i,j)
            print *, 'i',i, 'j', j,'sqa(i,j)',sqa(i,j)
        end do
    end do
end subroutine func
end module test

program main
use test
use mpi
implicit none
integer :: istart, iend, ierr,nproc, procnum, n,&
points_per_thread, i,j
integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: a, sqa
integer,dimension(mpi_status_size) :: status
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, nproc, ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,procnum, ierr)
if(procnum  == 0)then
    print *, 'enter no of rows'
    read *, n
end if
call mpi_bcast(n,1,mpi_integer,0,mpi_comm_world, ierr)
points_per_thread = (n + nproc - 1)/nproc
istart = procnum*points_per_thread + 1
iend = min((procnum + 1)*points_per_thread,n)
print *, 'istart ', istart, 'iend', iend, 'procnum', procnum
call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
allocate(a(istart:iend,2))
allocate(sqa(istart:iend,2))
do i = istart,iend
    do j = 1, 2
        a(i,j) = i +j
        print *, 'i =',i,'j =',j, a(i,j)
    end do
end do
call mpi_barrier(mpi_comm_world, ierr)
call func(a(istart:iend,:), sqa(istart:iend,:),istart,iend)
deallocate(a,sqa)
call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

The above code gives the segmentation fault error. I don't understand the reason for this.

Next, when in my subroutine func I change the declaration of arrays a and sqa to

```
integer,intent(in):: a(istart:iend,2)
integer, intent(out)::sqa(istart:iend,2)
```

Now it works fine. I request to kindly help me understand the reason for the error.

Comment: Welcome. Use tag [tag:fortran] for apl Fortran questions.

Comment: In which line does it crash? What does it print? Learn the debugging features of your compiler (like `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all` in gfortran and `-g -traceback -check` in ifort).

Comment: The lower bound of an assumed shape array is 1 by default. If you want it to be istart, you need to declare it as `array(istart:)`. See the duplicate link for more. Or just change the loop to `i = 1, size(a, 1)`

Comment: Would the use of coarrays provide any benefit here?

Comment: @VladimirF: Thank you.  The duplicate link solves my problem. I was initially thinking that passing the array to subroutine is done somewhat similar to passing by reference and bounds need not to be specified. I was unaware of this bound limits

Answer (score 1):

Assumed shape dummy arrays make available the extension of the actual arguments inside the function but not their bounds. If the actual bounds are needed inside the function, explicit-shape dummy arrays must be used.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Now I got it, but it is not very clear. We should have a duplicate.

Comment: It isn't true that explicit shape arrays must be used for bound information to be available.

Comment: It is true that passing the lower bound as argument (say lb) and declaring the array as dimension(lb:) keeps its syntactical nature of assumed shape array as defined in the standard. So, I was wrong writing that one has to use explicit-shape arrays. 
However, this is a corner where the language loses  part of its neat consistency,  even more if one think that in the case of a pointer the bounds are passed to the procedure, and it happens to me to consider differently the case where a lower bound passed as argument.