# Passing allocatable array into a subroutine

Tags: io, fortran, allocation, subroutine

I am working on a f90 code that I didn't write. I am not a very experienced fortran user.

There is a part that bothers me a bit and I am not sure if it is a normal practice. Can someone help me to clarify a bit please ?

- I have a structure with an allocatable array defined in a module.
- This variable is passed un-allocated to a subroutine.
- The subroutine then allocates its corresponding local variable.
- In the main, the output of the passed structure variable is allocated.

What I am not sure I understand is how the main program is handling the size of the return variable as it is not defined before. Is it a common practice?

Personally, I would have think that a variable with a defined size should have been passed to the subroutine.

If I resume coarsly the code:

**modulus_mod.f90**:

```
module modulus_mod
public :: mod

type mod
real,allocatable,dimension(:,:)    :: rec
end type mod

end module modulus_mod
```

**subtoto.f90**:

```
subroutine subtoto(recloc)

implicit none

real,allocatable,dimension(:,:)    :: recloc

WRITE(*,*) 'in'
ALLOCATE( recloc(10,10) )
WRITE(*,*) 'inout'
recloc(:,:)=1.
WRITE(*,*) 'out'

endsubroutine subtoto
```

**toto.f90**:

```
program toto
use modulus_mod

implicit none
type(mod)  :: model

!>>> Here not allocated if tested
if(allocated(model%rec)) WRITE(*,*) 'allocated bf'
if(.NOT.allocated(model%rec)) WRITE(*,*) 'NOT allocated bf'

CALL subtoto(model%rec)

WRITE(*,*) 'out sub'
!>>>Here it should be allocated correctly if tested
if(allocated(model%rec)) WRITE(*,*) 'allocated af'
if(.NOT.allocated(model%rec)) WRITE(*,*) 'NOT allocated af'

end program toto
```

Comment: You don't have a Fortran 90 program, from what you show. But what you do show is also not enough to be understandable as a Fortran Any program: if you want to show a real example, please make it a [mre] example.

Comment: That said, in current Fortran it's perfectly possible and plausible to allocate dummy arguments within a subroutine.  Not only possible, but a perfectly sensible design strategy. So can you please give more detail on the aspects you are struggling with?

Comment: It seems, perhaps, that you are not understanding concepts of _argument association_: the "local" argument (the so-called dummy) can be allocated and that directly affects the allocation of the _actual_ argument, the thing in the main program/module. You may find many questions if you search here using those sorts of terms.

Comment: Sorry for the bad minimal example.

Thank you for trying to clarify my lacking knowledge !
I tried to rewrite a minimal example but I got an error at the execution at the allocation statement in the subroutine, so it seems that I am missing something...

the error:
Fortran runtime error: Allocatable actual argument 'model' is not allocated

I updated my code above...

Comment: So if I understood well your comments, It should be possible to allocate in the subroutine  a variable that will be return to the main code even if not allocated a priori.
But I am unable to reproduce it. I will check your suggestion.

Comment: You need to be sure to give the program [an explicit interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13058743/3157076) for the subroutine `subtoto`. That isn't the case in your program.

Comment: Thank you francescalus !! my (main) lack of understanding seemed to be in this explicit interface ! I added a << contains\n include 'subtoto.f90'  >> in the module  and it works fine with the same comportment as the code on which I work actually.

Comment: Simple rule - put your subroutines in modules, that will satisfy the interface requirements

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make a hands-on summary here:

1. Variable is an `allocatable` dummy argument in a subroutine, for example:

```
subroutine sub(variable)
   real, allocatable, [intent(...)] :: variable(:)
```

here, status is controlled by the `intent` keyword:

- `intent(out)`: initially *not* allocated, when the subroutine is called
- `intent(in)`, `intent(inout)` or [no intent declared]: initial allocation status depends on what the variable was like outside of this routine

At any times, you can check both the status and the size of this variable by
`allocated(variable)` and `size(variable)`.

Note that size is *undefined if the variable is not allocated*, so you may want to use something like:

```
safe_size = merge(size(variable),-1,allocated(variable))
```

to prevent the undefined behavior.

2. Variable is in a module: it is `save`d. Its status is `not allocated` at the beginning of the program; both status and contents can change during runtime (for example being changed by a subroutine or function, with the rules of 1.), but nothing is modified between these calls.

In your case, if you want your variable to *always* be allocated by the routine, you should specify an `intent(out)`, like:

```
subroutine subtoto(recloc)
   implicit none
   real,allocatable,dimension(:,:), intent(out) :: recloc
   [...]
end subroutine subtoto
```

Comment: Why do you suggest `merge(size(variable),-1,allocated(variable))` is useful? `size(variable)` as an expression must be evaluated in the reference to the function `merge`, but can be evaluated only if `variable` is allocated.

Comment: If that's what your comment wants to say, then it's wrong. In a Fortran program `merge(size(variable),-1,allocated(variable))` can never return the value `-1`. `size(variable)` will _always_ be evaluated.

Comment: If `variable` is not allocated, then `size(variable)` must not be evaluated. In the reference to `merge(size(variable), ..., ...)`, however, `size(variable)` is evaluated, regardless of however the other arguments to the function evaluate. Which means, this reference to `merge` is valid only if `variable` is allocated and the reference must evaluate to `size(variable)` (which can never be `-1`). Perhaps you can explain why you think what you've written is "compact" and avoids undefined behaviour?

Comment: I'm not saying that `size(variable)` is undefined if `variable` is not allocated. I'm saying that a valid Fortran program cannot evaluate `size(variable)` if `variable` is not allocated. Something like `merge(x, 0, .false.)` is allowed even if `x` is undefined, but this is because `x` is a variable instead of an expression (`merge((x),0,.false.)` is _not_ allowed if `x` is undefined).

Comment: Thank you a lot to you both, I solved my problem and will dig in your helpful comment to improve myself !